# jQuery - Close other groups when a new one is opened

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please could you help me to make this work, what I am trying to do is this.

When clicking on a group at the moment the new group opens and the ones that are already open stay open.

I want to close all others and have open only the active group.

The example can be found below:

```js
var accordionsMenu = $('.cd-accordion-menu');

if (accordionsMenu.length > 0) {

  accordionsMenu.each(function() {
    var accordion = $(this);
    accordion.on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
      var checkbox = $(this);
      (checkbox.prop('checked')) ? checkbox.siblings('ul').attr('style', 'display:none;').slideDown(300): checkbox.siblings('ul').attr('style', 'display:block;').slideUp(300);
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<h1>Multi-Level Accordion Menu</h1>

<ul class="cd-accordion-menu animated">
  <li class="has-children">
    <input type="checkbox" name="group-1" id="group-1">
    <label for="group-1">Group 1</label>

    <ul>
      <li class="has-children">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub-group-1" id="sub-group-1">
        <label for="sub-group-1">Sub Group 1</label>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
          <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
          <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="has-children">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub-group-2" id="sub-group-2">
        <label for="sub-group-2">Sub Group 2</label>

        <ul>
          <li class="has-children">
            <input type="checkbox" name="sub-group-level-3" id="sub-group-level-3">
            <label for="sub-group-level-3">Sub Group Level 3</label>

            <ul>
              <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
              <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="has-children">
    <input type="checkbox" name="group-2" id="group-2">
    <label for="group-2">Group 2</label>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="has-children">
    <input type="checkbox" name="group-3" id="group-3">
    <label for="group-3">Group 3</label>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="has-children">
    <input type="checkbox" name="group-4" id="group-4">
    <label for="group-4">Group 4</label>

    <ul>
      <li class="has-children">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub-group-3" id="sub-group-3">
        <label for="sub-group-3">Sub Group 3</label>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
          <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- cd-accordion-menu -->
```

UPDATE: [WORKING VERSION HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/JNfrontend/pds87bhr/)

CREDIT: @jeto

Comment: Please work out a minimal example without all unrelated styling which only contains the necessary htm elements and script to make the accordion behavior work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the HTML from your fiddle, something like this should work:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.cd-accordion-menu input[type="checkbox"]')
    .on('change', function(e) {
      // Retrieve the sibling <li>'s
      var $sameLevelSiblings = $(this).closest('li').siblings();

      // Uncheck the corresponding checkboxes and hide the items
      $sameLevelSiblings.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
      $sameLevelSiblings.find('ul').slideUp(300);

      // Display or hide the current items depending on checkbox state
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown(300);
      } else {
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp(300);
      }
    })
    // Hide all items on load
    .siblings('ul').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Multi-Level Accordion Menu</h1>

<ul class="cd-accordion-menu animated">
  <li class="has-children">
    <input type="checkbox" name="group-1" id="group-1">
    <label for="group-1">Group 1</label>

    <ul>
      <li class="has-children">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub-group-1" id="sub-group-1">
        <label for="sub-group-1">Sub Group 1</label>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
          <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
          <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="has-children">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub-group-2" id="sub-group-2">
        <label for="sub-group-2">Sub Group 2</label>

        <ul>
          <li class="has-children">
            <input type="checkbox" name="sub-group-level-3" id="sub-group-level-3">
            <label for="sub-group-level-3">Sub Group Level 3</label>

            <ul>
              <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
              <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="has-children">
    <input type="checkbox" name="group-2" id="group-2">
    <label for="group-2">Group 2</label>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="has-children">
    <input type="checkbox" name="group-3" id="group-3">
    <label for="group-3">Group 3</label>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="has-children">
    <input type="checkbox" name="group-4" id="group-4">
    <label for="group-4">Group 4</label>

    <ul>
      <li class="has-children">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub-group-3" id="sub-group-3">
        <label for="sub-group-3">Sub Group 3</label>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
          <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- cd-accordion-menu -->
```

Note: using HTML elements/attributes for selectors is bad practice, I'd recommend using `data-` attributes instead.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks, @jeto ;)

I did try to add animation when the group is closing, 

    $sameLevelSiblings.find('ul').slideUp();

but it's creating some weird jumping. There is an option to add animation and avoid the issue with jumping?

Comment: @JustFrontend I've edited the snippet to include the slide effect. Is this OK? You might still see a small "jump" at the start when you run it, to avoid it just have all your items be hidden at HTML level so that it doesn't have to be done by script.

Comment: Hi @Jeto, is perfect now! Really big thanks for your help!

Comment: @JustFrontend You're welcome, happy to help. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.